# What is bug in jdk6 compiler due to which hibernate ORM require JDK 7 compiler or plus?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, java-7, java-6

Under **System Requirements** section in documentation of Hibernate ORM 4+ it is officially  mentioned that

> building Hibernate from source requires JDK 7 due to a bug in the JDK
>   6 compiler

I am looking for bug which doesnt make Hibernate compatible with jdk6 compiler.

[Hibernate Documentation](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/getting-started/)

Comment: Do you actually want to recompile Hibernate from source? What's the point? If you actually want to use Hibernate 4 in an application with JDK 6, just use Hibernate 4.2.8.Final version. I think there is a bug with Hibernate 4.3 and JDK 6, but 4.2.8 works fine

Comment: Want to know whether that is well known bug. I am more curious about bug.